# how to read and write specific word in a line from txt in c# console

Tags: c#, console-application

i need to get the product code,price and stock for  calculation on the txt file that contain

```
//product code;product name;price;stock;
c01;cappuccino;3500;12;
c02;mocaccino;4000;15;
c03;black coffe;3000;10;
c04;chocolate milk;5000;19;
c05;vanilla milk;5000;12;
c06;strawberry milk;5000;13;
c07;coke;3000;13;
c08;fanta;3000;15;
c09;sprite;3000;9;
c10;orange juice;4500;10;
c11;apple juice;4500;9;
c12;mango juice;4500;18;
```

i've tried

```
if(line.Contains(""))
```

but the **line** in line.contains give error red underline instead, am i missing using namespace for this?

also i've tried

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("product.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string str = sr.ReadLine();
    while (str != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", str);
        str = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    fs.Close();
```

as practice to get a word, but it return all contents from txt instead

Comment: _"but the line in line.contains give error red underline instead, am i missing using..."_ - **Pro Tip**: If you move your mouse over the red underline/squiggle and hover there for a moment, Visual Studio will display a tool-tip describing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following class and code, you will be able to extract the data you need in order to do calculations and other manipulations.

It basically reads the file line by line and parses them to the object.
The first line is being skipped by checking for `"//"`.

Hope this suits your needs.

**Product Class**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
```

**File Parsing**

```
var products = new List<Product>();

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("product.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string line;
    while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((line = streamReader.ReadLine())))
    {
        if (!line.StartsWith("//"))
        {
            var lineSplit = line.Split(';');
            products.Add(new Product
            {
                Code = lineSplit[0],
                Name = lineSplit[1],
                Price = Decimal.Parse(lineSplit[2]),
                Stock = Int32.Parse(lineSplit[3])
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i tried `Console.WriteLine(linesplit[0]);` it return all product code, how do i get only single product code?

Comment: Short and sweet, understandable enough. Nonetheless, I like better how it looks in F# (see http://ideone.com/ltCwka). :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate throught those values you can make it like this:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("c:\\file.txt"));

while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
var line = streamReader.ReadLine()
var values = line.Split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(values[i]); //example usage
}
```